Why is γίγας κυνηγὸς translated as Mighty Hunter in Genesis 10:9 according to the LXX?
Genesis 10:9 says, "He was a mighty hunter before the Lord God; because of this they will say, “As Nimrod was a mighty hunter before the Lord.”
According to the LXX, the greek word γίγας is translated as either as migthy or giant.
Why is mighty used in the context of Gen 10:9 instead of giant?

Since words all have a semantic range of meaning, given the context of Genesis 10, the word “mighty” is the more probable meaning.  Just as in Isaiah 45:7, the Hebrew word “Ra” can mean “disaster” or “calamity” or “evil” — and in Isaiah 45:7, since it is a form of parallelism, the opposite of “peace” is “calamity”, the NKJV renders the word “Ra” better than the KJV, unless somebody knows about archaic English use that infers “evil” as in “natural evil” as opposed to moral evil.  But to your question, “giant” is an unlikely interpretation and translation of Gen 10:9.

γίγαντας (gígantas) which in English means Giant(1) in the LXX is used in Numbers 13:33, to refer to the “giants” since Moses recorded the people in the land of Canaan as follows: “and all the people whom we saw in it are men of great stature.”  and Moses also says: “and we were like grasshoppers in our own sight, and so we were in their sight.”
This passage in the book of Numbers seems to adequately reflect the word of a “giant” in the LXX rendering, given the context.
As it says in Num 13:33: “…There we saw the giants (the descendants of Anak came from the giants…”
In Genesis 10:9, there seems to be nothing in the context of the passage to lend support to translating it as “giant” as compared with the example from Numbers 13:33.
It would appear that “mighty” is the proper translation here.
For more questions on biblical translation, see: “40 Questions about Bible Translation, by Mark L. Strauss”.
Sources:
(1): https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-meaning-of/greek-word-5bf2bc34738abd9c9cbdcab2c69a8934e1b847f5.html

The operative adjective used in gen 10:9 is גִּבּוֹר (gibbor) which means "strong, mighty" (Strongs).
As the OP correctly points out, the LXX translates this word (rather surprisingly) as γίγας (gigas) = "giant".  The Brenton translation of the LXX translates this literally as:

He was a giant hunter before the Lord God; therefore they say, As
Nebrod the giant hunter before the Lord.

Now, why the LXX did not use a closer word in meaning to the Hebrew like μέγας, μεγάλη, μέγα, (= "great") etc, we do not know.

Spec. 4:120 PHE

Now many of the lawgivers both among the Greeks and barbarians, praise those who are skillful in hunting, and who seldom fail in their pursuit or miss their aim, and who pride themselves on their successful hunts, especially when they divide the limbs of the animals which they have caught with the huntsmen and the hounds, as being not only brave hunters but men of very sociable dispositions. But any one who was a sound interpreter of the sacred constitution and code of laws would very naturally blame them, since the lawgiver of that code has expressly forbidden any enjoyment of carcasses or of bodies torn by beasts for the reasons before mentioned.

In Genesis 10:9, Nimrod is famously described as a "mighty hunter before the Lord," which, in the Greek of the LXX, reads γίγας κυνηγὸς ἐναντίον Κυρίου. This translation emphasizes not just Nimrod’s hunting prowess but his significant strength and impact. Philo’s text, particularly Spec. 4:116–120, helps explain the nuanced implications of the term "hunter" (κυνηγὸς) and why a figure associated with "hunting" might also carry a moral or ethical dimension in ancient Jewish thought.
Philo describes various kinds of animals and their uses, suggesting a moral perspective on different types of hunting. He praises those who refrain from harming peaceful creatures or engaging in wanton destruction of animals simply for sport. Instead, he criticizes the δεινοὺς κυνηγούς (skilled hunters), who hunt not just for sustenance but also to indulge in excessive displays of dominance, even dividing spoils with dogs and other hunters as a form of boastful pride.
Applying Philo’s perspective to Genesis 10:9, "hunter" in the LXX could imply more than literal hunting. Nimrod, as a γίγας κυνηγὸς (mighty hunter), may represent a person who dominated others aggressively and sought power or fame in a way Philo might view critically. In this light, Nimrod’s hunting could symbolize his pursuit of domination and control, even in opposition to divine or moral order.
Therefore, Philo’s ethical views on hunting reinforce that the Septuagint’s description of Nimrod as a γίγας κυνηγὸς isn't only about physical prowess but might also hint at a morally ambiguous character who exemplifies a form of dominion that Philo and the ancient Jewish worldview could consider excessive or prideful.
